# Rewrite public_html document root to a folder in root directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

So I have 2 sites, just call them `example.com` and `admin.example.com`.

- `example.com` is listed in my cPanel with the document root being **/home/username/public_html** (unchangeable), but the actual file is stored in **home/username/example-site**.
- `admin.example.com` is listed with document root **home/username/public_html/admin**.

Directory structure:

```
home/username
|- example-site
|...
|- public_html
   |- admin
```

Those 2 sites were built with different framework. And now, without a proper .htaccess file, when I try to access `example.com` it shows lists of files in the public_html folder, and `admin.example.com` works fine.

Therefore, I'm trying to move my document root for `example.com` from **/home/username/public_html** to **/home/username/example-site** with a .htaccess file, but I can't seem to find a proper format to suit my need. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not what rewriting does. If you want to change the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your http host you need to change the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you move the folder "example-site" into the folder "public_html" (you might also want to rename it):

```
home/username
|...
|- public_html
   |- example-site
   |- admin
```

Then you implement a rewriting rule that maps all requests that do *not* specify the admin subdomain as http host into that folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example-site/
RewriteRule ^ /example-site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

As an alternative you can also implement a positive condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example-site/
RewriteRule ^ /example-site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion to move the folder inside public_html and set redirects using above format. Now, the `example.com` works fine, but after I login from `admin.example.com/login` and get redirected to `admin.example.com`, the admin homepage shows the same content as the `example.com` homepage

Comment: Hm, strange... How is that redirection done? Could you please examine that using the browser's development console?

Comment: Do you have any other rewriting rules in place? The issue could also be the result of a colision...

Comment: Actually I do, I just remembered that. In the .htaccess inside my admin folder, I define another rewrite and by now I have removed all the rewrites (.htaccess in admin is empty, .htaccess in public_html is as above), but `admin.example.com` homepage still show the same content as `example.com` homepage

Comment: I fail to spot the issue of the cause...  I suspect that the issue is _not_ the rewriting rules, but the rest of the setup. What happens if you comment out that rewriting rule above and request "admin.example.com"?

Comment: still the same, i guess it's really because of the setup

Comment: My guess: either you are looking at cached results or the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for "admin.example.com" points to the wring location.